# When to connect objects between the interface builder and header file?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, interface-builder

This is probably a really newb question but the book i'm using (Learning iOS programming) doesn't really explain it well so i'm asking here.

When i drag a UITextFieldn onto my view, I know I can ctrl click from it into my header file so that instance of a textfield (textField1 for example) has been declared and then later synthesised (.m file).

I can also do the typing in the .h manually and then connect the UITextField as the referencing outlet of the UITexField called textField1.

This makes sense since I want to programmatically change the text, font etc so there needs to be a connection.

Is this the only reason we declare an object in the header file?

I ask because i've been watching videos on how to use Gesture Recognizers and nobody seems to declare those in the .h. Is it because they're minipulating those solely through the interface builder?

I'd just like a bit of info on what the rules are regarding this.

Edit: I guess my question isn't if I have to decalre it in the .h file (as opposed the the .m) but why do I have to declare a gesture recognizer at all if i'll never use it outside the interface builder?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can recommend reading this short but effective article about ["Private properties, methods and ivars in Objective-C"](http://www.benjaminloulier.com/posts/private-properties-methods-and-ivars-in-objective-c/) to learn about the "why and how" of encapsulation in Objective-C.

Furthermore, if you have a look at the [Xcode User Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode_User_Guide/030-Edit_User_Interfaces/edit_user_interface.html), it states that you don't necessarily need to declare the outlets in the header file and could also declare it in the implementation (.m) file. Doing so offers the benefit of not exposing your outlet, which I guess is the same intention why the gesture recognizers in these tutorials were declared inside the implementation file.

Comment: I guess what i'm asking is why do I need declare it at all?

Comment: if you just need to use the gesture recognizer within an action method, you don't need to create and connect an outlet for it, but could simply use the recognizer that gets passed as a parameter to the action method, like so: `@implementation
- (IBAction)displayGestureForTapRecognizer:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
     // use the gesture recognizer here
}` .. is that what you meant?

Comment: Exactly what I meant, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The only difference between declaring your outlets in the .h and the .m is visibility for other classes that use your view controller.

The question you'd like to ask yourself is if someone outside that specific view controller should know about the existence of your view or not. I recommend you to define all instance variables inside the .m file, and move them to the .h file only when needed (and before you move them, think again if that's a good design decision - on common scenarios the view controller should handle all its views by itself).